# How can I change folder permissions on a remote computer using the command line?

Tags: windows, command-line

Is there any DOS command present using which I can change permission for a folder which reside on a remote computer. Appreciate your help on this.

Thanks.

Comment: Actual DOS or some sort of command prompt/script?  What operating system exactly?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is no such command specifically for this but you can use `icacls` command this way to achive the same

```
icacls \\Server_name\E$\test /grant:r "DOMAIN\%user%$":(OI)(CI)F
```

Hope this helps others

Answer (score -1):

```
P:\>attrib /?
Displays or changes file attributes.

ATTRIB [+R | -R] [+A | -A ] [+S | -S] [+H | -H] [+I | -I]
       [drive:][path][filename] [/S [/D] [/L]]

  +   Sets an attribute.
  -   Clears an attribute.
  R   Read-only file attribute.
  A   Archive file attribute.
  S   System file attribute.
  H   Hidden file attribute.
  I   Not content indexed file attribute.
  [drive:][path][filename]
      Specifies a file or files for attrib to process.
  /S  Processes matching files in the current folder
      and all subfolders.
  /D  Processes folders as well.
  /L  Work on the attributes of the Symbolic Link versus
      the target of the Symbolic Link

md test
attrib +A test
```

Comment: This changes attributes, not permissions